# How to construct a list of products recursively in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following type table,

```
create table products (
    productid varchar(10),
    make varchar(10),
    age varchar(10),
    colour varchar(10),
    category1 varchar(10),
    category2 varchar(10),
    caregory3 varchar(10)
    )
```

I would like to select a list of products (all the fields) but there should be only one product per `make`. The product that gets selected for each `make` should be determined by applying a set of rules in order. For example,
- If there exists a red product belonging to a particular `make`, select this product.
- For all `make` not yet represented, select a product that is less than two years old.
- For all `make` not yet represented, select a product that is category 1 value of x
- excreta

You can do this by maintaining some memory/temporary table of selected product, and insert into this table additional products only when it does not yet contain a potential product's make. By applying one `insert select into` per rule in order the memory/temporary table is filled up. Eg.

```
insert into #temp 
select productid, make, age, colour, category1, category2, caregory3 
from products a 
where *rule applies*
and a.make not exists in (select make from #temp where a.make = #temp.make)
```

This does not seem very elegant however.

*Note: This is a simplification of the actual problem. In the actual problem there can only be one valid product on each selection level.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.make ORDER BY 
    CASE 
      WHEN colour = 'red' THEN 1
      WHEN age < '2' THEN 2
      WHEN category1 = 'x' THEN 3
      ELSE 4
    END) as priority
    FROM products p 
) ranked
WHERE priority = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursors could be used for this, in conjunction with a table variable to store selected products:

```
DECLARE @selected_products table(
    productid varchar(10),
    make varchar(10),
    age varchar(10),
    colour varchar(10),
    category1 varchar(10),
    category2 varchar(10),
    caregory3 varchar(10)
)

DECLARE @current_make varchar(10)

DECLARE make_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT DISTINCT make FROM products

OPEN make_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM make_cursor INTO @current_make

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @red_product_count int

    SELECT @red_product_count = COUNT(productid)
    FROM products
    WHERE colour = 'red'

    IF @red_product_count > 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 productid, make, age, colour, category1, category2, category3
        INTO @selected_products
        FROM products
        ORDER BY some_field

    END

END
CLOSE make_cursor
DEALLOCATE make_cursor
```

The documentation for cursors can be found at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

You can then use additional flow-control logic to apply your rules, and even nest cursors to get the desired results. There are more examples in the documentation.